# How to rotate from different titles

Tags: javascript

No, I am not talking about `<h1>` or something like that. I am talking about the `<title>` element. I created a function, that delays every .5 seconds or so, and changes titles.

The script I have developed reads the array, which includes the titles, and rotates from it. The first time I have ran it, I did not use `setTimeout`, and it ran instantly, I couldnt read anything.

But when I tried using the `setTimeout` function, it started to return `undefined`. What is the problem with this code?

```js
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length ; i++){
              setTimeout(function () {document.title = titles[i]}, 500)
}
```

Comment: assuming `titles` is an array of strings, try `document.title.innerHTML=titles[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way (IMO). Using a loop you'll fire off all your `timeout`s at once. You'd be better off using `setInterval`

```js
let i = 0, titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'];
let int = setInterval(() => {
  document.title = titles[i];
  console.log('doc.title: ', document.title);
  if (i++ >= titles.length - 1) clearInterval(int);
}, 500)
```

Comment: Or, if you would like to cycle the titles, you can use `i = (i + 1) % titles.length` instead of line 5.

Comment: This worked, thanks m8

Comment: @Hetrogon - cool. If this answered your question, consider closing it out by marking it as the solution. Thanks